# Search for files containing specific numbers with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of file Id's

[image]

and I want to find the system feed files containing any of these numbers from a vast directory using powershell.

I was using `Get-Content Cash* -totalcount 1 > cash_Check_outputfile.txt`
but as each file contains numerous headers this was not working as I hoped.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: you might be able to use get-childitem to find the files you want, then use select-string to check those files for the numbers. `help select-string`

Comment: I basically just want to know if there is an easy way for me to find which files on a windows directory contain any of the numbers in my id list

Comment: And where you stuck? Do you already loaded the list into your script? Do you search for the file name or for the file itself? Do you need to match all files or only some extensions? Do the file need to match exactly or is it enough that the id is within it? Im missing a lot of information in your question....

Comment: okay I will try to explain better..... I would like advice on how to code a powershell command that will look through my list of id's and then return any files that contain that id in the file.  nothing more than just containing the id in the file.  does that make it any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to retrieve all files and use the [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet to find the files containing any number within your dictionary (`$test` in this example). Finally, use the [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) cmdlet to get the path.

```
$test = @(
    707839
    709993
)

$pathToSearch = 'C:\test'    
Get-ChildItem $pathToSearch | Select-String $test | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

Comment: Or more compactly, `(Select-String $test $pathWithMask).path`.  This Select-String syntax does require the path to be a file mask like `C:\temp\*` and not just a folder name though.

Comment: Great help.  Thanks for all answers